# How to configuring Azure AD sso to allow guest logins

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

I have a php application that I want active directory users to be able to login to using azure sso.  Getting this working with simplesamlphp was really easy.

Now I am trying to allow non organization users to be able to login as guests.
I updated azure AD to allow external entities, and then created a workflow allowing AD users, microsoft.com accounts and one time password.  I have enabled "guest self-service signup" and I have associated this user flow with my azure application however the authentication flow hasn't changed at all.  There isn't any option for guests to login.  Am I missing something?  I am using the azure ad federation metadata document xml in the simplesaml metadata converter and using the output of that for my metadata provider in simplesaml.

Here is the screen a user gets when trying to sign in to azure:
[image]

Comment: What happens when a guest enters their email address and logs in?

Comment: I was confused on how all this works.  Guests and AD users use the exact same login process.  You have to create the guest user/password in AD ahead of time before they can actually login as a guest.